# How to use notes2bib with per-chapter bibliographies?

Tags: bibliographies, notes2bib

When `notes2bib` is used with chapters it changes how the database references are generated. This breaks the `\citenote{}` command as there is no longer a user-defined key for bibnotes.

From the manual:

> When usingbiblatex’s *refsection* system, additional information is added to all labels from the second *refsection* onward (i.e.to all except *refsection* 0). This additional text is added before the note name, and always includes the *refsection* number.

There is more text after that, but it just specifies how to change that text, not how to disable this behaviour.

This has an issue, as I want to use the same footnote more then once.

MWE showing the issue:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{filecontents}{footnote.bib}
@Article{Brown,
    author ="Brown, Matthew L. and Van Wieren, Ken and Tailor, Hamel N. and Hartling, David and Jean, Anthony and Merbouh, Nabyl",
    title  ="Three-dimensional printing of ellipsoidal structures using Mercury",
    journal  ="CrystEngComm",
    year  ="2018",
    doi  ="10.1039/C7CE01901G",
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=chem-rsc,
    refsection=chapter+    
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{notes2bib}

\addbibresource{footnote.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter[]{3D Printing of Crystallographic Data}
This is example text\autocite{Brown}
Now this is text that needs a bibnote\bibnote[round]{Structure measured with calipers and rounded to the nearest}%
Now I need to refer to that bibnote again\citenote{round}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Now, I could manually set the format of the text it adds to the key, and refer to it that way (or just look up what it is assigned in the database file), but that would require manual editing every time the chapter number changes, which it will (i.e. when I am working on Ch1 I turn it off to save compile time, but that will change all the other chapters numbers...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\citenote{label}` function was deprecated between versions 1 and 2 of the `notes2bib` package, in favour of `\bibnotemark[label]`. (Presumably for reasons relating to this.)

Replacing it in your text as below seems to make the output you're after.

```latex
Now this is text that needs a bibnote\bibnote[round]{Structure measured with calipers and rounded to the nearest}  % 
Now I need to refer to that bibnote again\bibnotemark[round].
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't think to check if the citation mechanism had changed since I wrote the paper I'm copying, or think to check I was using the latest version of the documentation.

Comment: Oh, you also use [] now, that is...odd, but OK